# org-babel: Make results always quote the returned value in #+begin_example

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, github

Github's org parser has a bug where they mistakenly show

```
#+begin_src bsh.dash :results verbatim :exports both
echo | time possiblycat 1000
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:
: possiblycat 1000  0.00s user 0.00s system 75% cpu 0.006 total; max RSS 1852
```

as

[image]

(I have reported this on [Github](https://github.community/t/bug-in-parsing-org-mode/133188).)

I want to workaround this by quoting the result:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
...
#+end_example
```

How can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output` variable will help you  accomplish  this.

I've set the following in my configuration files in order to make `#+RESULTS` code blocks be always enclosed within `#+begin_example` blocks

```
(setq org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output 0)
```

Here's an example

```
#+begin_src cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "a";
  return 0;
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
a
#+end_example
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer:

```
#+begin_src bsh.dash :results verbatim :exports both :wrap "example"
echo | time possiblycat 1000
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example

possiblycat 1000  0.00s user 0.00s system 68% cpu 0.005 total; max RSS 1888
#+end_example
```